# Fastest memory transfer from Node.js plugin to JavaScript/WebGL

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, webgl

I have a C++ DLL that is transferring images every 50ms in raw RGB format, these will be around 1280x800 so about 3MB each.  I want to ideally be able to display these at 50ms as well.  I'm not super familiar with Node and Javascript, still learning, so want to make sure I head down the right path without spending too much time struggling with an unworkable solution.

Basic idea:

- create a C++ Node plugin that pulls this data, spin this off in its own child process thats called at 50ms
- pass a Buffer into the exposed function, gets populated by the plugin
- use this buffer as the RGB texture data for gl.texSubImage2D in WebGL context

Questions:

- if I spin off the C++ plugin into its own process is the Buffer declared there available outside that process for use in the WebGL context?
- im pretty sure I cant use Buffer data directly for a WebGL texture and this will involve a copy at some point to get it to a usable type - correct?

Is something like this workable?

Does anyone have any experience in something like this?

Comment: not sure about the first question, though in general memory is not shared across processes unless you explicitly share it, maybe you meant threads? but, for the 2nd question you should use a [`typedarray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) not a `Buffer`, then you can pass it directly into WebGL. Also note that most drivers will expand RGB to RGBA so you can avoid that overhead in the driver if you do it yourself.

Comment: Note there are also [`SharedArrayBuffers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) in electron

Comment: @gman Thank you.  After some research it looked like Buffers were the only way to efficiently pass large amounts of data between JS and a Node C++ plugin.  I'll look at your two suggestions, thanks again.